# Errors when applying AWS eb commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html

I'm trying to follow these steps to deploy an example of an Express application for the first time. After installing the Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface (EB CLI), I can apply eb commands in the Command Prompt (using Windows 10). After initializing a Git repository, I should use commands to configure an EB CLI repository.

These command are being applied in the directory of an an ExpressJS project:

1. First I enter the command: **eb init – platform Node.js – region us-east-2** which results in the message in a separate window **Application AWS2 has been created.**
2. Next I enter command: **eb create – sample node-express-env** which results in the error message **ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - Environment node-express-env already exists.**
3. Then when I enter the command: **eb open** the message says **ERROR: This branch does not have a default environment. You must either specify an environment by typing "eb open my-env-name" or set a default environment by typing "eb use my-env-name".**
4. Then when I enter: **eb open node-express-env** there's another message **ERROR: NotFoundError - Environment "node-express-env" not Found.** which contradicts the message from 2.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: did you try eb use node-express-env?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that, you configured the CLI to use the same region in which your environment is created.

Comment: us-east-2 is my region on AWS

Comment: Did you configured the eb cli, using eb init  and select the default region ?